# Multiple Negative LookAhead on - US SSN

Tags: regex

Hi I have a writing a regex to validate US SSNs with the following conditions:

1. All digits are identical
2. 123456789 or 987654321
3. First three digits are either 000 or 666
4. Middle two digits are 00 or last four digits are 0000

I am currently using this regex for these criteria.

```
 ^(?!(\d)\1{8})(?!123456789)(?!987654321)(?!0{3})(?!6{3})(?!\d{3}0{2}\d{4})(?!\d{3}\d{2}0{4})\d{9}$|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

And it rejects the following samples except for the last one.

```
555555555
555005555
222540000
123456789
987654321
000917642
666082134
231564365
```

However, when i try to create a variation of the same regex to account for (-) dashes.

```
^(?!(\d)\1{2}-(\d)\1{1}-(\d)\1{3})(?!123-45-6789)(?!987-65-4321)(?!0{3}-(\d)\1{1}-(\d)\1{2})(?!0{6}-(\d)\1{1}-(\d)\1{2})(?!\d{3}-0{2}-\d{4})(?!\d{3}-\d{2}-0{4})\d{9}$|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

None of them seem to be invalidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you express the regex like this:

```
^(?!(\d)\1{2}-?(\d)\1{1}-?(\d)\1{3})(?!123-?45-?6789)(?!987-?65-?4321)(?!0{3}-?(\d)\1{1}-?(\d)\1{2})(?!0{6}-?(\d)\1{1}-?(\d)\1{2})(?!\d{3}-?0{2}-?\d{4})(?!\d{3}-?\d{2}-?0{4})\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$
```

you can get rid of the last OR, and will work both for dashed or non-dashed inputs.

Sample here: http://regex101.com/r/jK9eC5

Comment: Thanks! I missed that part.